# Timer for a Java game

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have a simple game that implements a `TimerTask`. However, when there's a popup using `JOptionPane` the timer task doesn't seem to actually pause. I know I could maybe find a way to pause the TimerTask when there's a popup until the user input happens but I'd rather just work on using the best timer method from the get go. I'm looking for a code review especially on how I use `TimerTask` and if I should rewrite my code with Swing timer or some other timer method.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GameBoard extends JPanel {

    public final static int EARTH_ORBIT_RADIUS = 200;
    public final static int BOARD_WIDTH = 800;
    public final static int BOARD_HEIGHT = 600;
    public final static int INITIAL_EARTH_X = 700;
    public final static int INITIAL_EARTH_Y = 300;
    public final static int INITIAL_DELAY = 100;
    public final static int PERIOD_DELAY = 50;
    public final static int SUN_COORDINATE_X = 400;
    public final static int SUN_COORDINATE_Y = 300;
    public final static int INITIAL_ASTEROID_X = 500;
    public final static int INITIAL_ASTEROID_Y = 100;
    public final static int INITIAL_SHIP_X = 500;
    public final static int INITIAL_SHIP_Y = 500;

    public static int earth_x, earth_y;
    public static int asteroid_x, asteroid_y;
    public static int asteroid_x_previous = INITIAL_ASTEROID_X, asteroid_y_previous = INITIAL_ASTEROID_Y;
    public static int asteroid_velocity_x = 0, asteroid_velocity_y = 0;
    public static int ship_x, ship_y;
    public static int ship_x_previous = INITIAL_SHIP_X, ship_y_previous = INITIAL_SHIP_Y;
    public static int velocity_x = 0, velocity_y = 0;
    public int t = 0;
    public int ship_t = 0;
    public int keyheard = 0;
    public int[] earthcoordinates;
    public int[] asteroidcoordinates;
    public int[] shipcoordinates;
    public static String current_ship;

    public static CollisionDetector c = new CollisionDetector();
    public static boolean isCollision = false;
    public static boolean we_are_mining = false;
    public static int mining_choice;

    Image earth;
    Image sun;
    Image asteroid;
    Image background;
    Image shipA, ship, shipL, shipR, shipU, shipD;

    Timer timer;

    JLabel rocketfuel_text = new JLabel();
    JLabel metals_text = new JLabel();

    GameBoard() {




        initGameBoard();
        keyListen();
        loadImage();


        earth_x = INITIAL_EARTH_X;
        earth_y = INITIAL_EARTH_Y;

        asteroid_x = INITIAL_ASTEROID_X;
        asteroid_y = INITIAL_ASTEROID_Y;

        ship_x = INITIAL_SHIP_X;
        ship_y = INITIAL_SHIP_Y;

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduledTask(), INITIAL_DELAY,
                PERIOD_DELAY);
    }

    void initGameBoard(){

        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT));
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        //addKeyListener(new KeyListen());
        setFocusable(true);

        rocketfuel_text.setVisible(true);
        rocketfuel_text.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        this.add(rocketfuel_text);

        metals_text.setVisible(true);
        metals_text.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        this.add(metals_text);

    }

    void loadImage() {
        ImageIcon earth_image_icon = new ImageIcon("earth2.png");
        earth = earth_image_icon.getImage();

        ImageIcon sun_image_icon = new ImageIcon("sun.png");
        sun = sun_image_icon.getImage(); 

        ImageIcon asteroid_image_icon = new ImageIcon("asteroid.png");
        asteroid = asteroid_image_icon.getImage();

        ImageIcon bg_image_icon = new ImageIcon("bg_pr.png");
        background = bg_image_icon.getImage();

        ImageIcon shipA_image_icon = new ImageIcon("ship_alpha.png");
        shipA = shipA_image_icon.getImage();

        ImageIcon ship_image_icon = new ImageIcon("ship_beta.png");
        ship = ship_image_icon.getImage();

        ImageIcon shipL_image_icon = new ImageIcon("ship_betaL.png");
        shipL = shipL_image_icon.getImage();

        ImageIcon shipR_image_icon = new ImageIcon("ship_betaR.png");
        shipR = shipR_image_icon.getImage();

        ImageIcon shipU_image_icon = new ImageIcon("ship_betaU.png");
        shipU = shipU_image_icon.getImage();

        ImageIcon shipD_image_icon = new ImageIcon("ship_betaD.png");
        shipD = shipD_image_icon.getImage();


    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        drawBackground(g);
        drawEarth(g);
        drawSun(g);
        drawAsteroid(g);
        drawShip(g);

    }

    void drawEarth(Graphics g) {

        g.drawImage(earth, earth_x, earth_y, this);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    }

    void drawSun(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(sun, SUN_COORDINATE_X, SUN_COORDINATE_Y, this);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    }

    void drawAsteroid(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(asteroid, asteroid_x, asteroid_y, this);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    }

    void drawBackground(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
    }

    void drawShip(Graphics g){
        if(keyheard == 0 || c.whoCollision() == "earth"){g.drawImage(ship,ship_x, ship_y, this);}
        else if(c.whoCollision() == "asteroid"){g.drawImage(shipA, ship_x, ship_y, this);}
        else if(keyheard == 1){g.drawImage(shipL,ship_x, ship_y, this); current_ship =  "shipL";}
        else if(keyheard == 2){g.drawImage(shipR,ship_x, ship_y, this); current_ship =  "shipR";}
        else if(keyheard == 3){g.drawImage(shipU,ship_x, ship_y, this); current_ship =  "shipU";}
        else if(keyheard == 4){g.drawImage(shipD,ship_x, ship_y, this); current_ship =  "shipD";}
        else if(keyheard == 5){g.drawImage(ship,ship_x, ship_y, this); current_ship =  "ship";}

    }
    public class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {



        @Override
        public void run() {


            OrbitCalculation oe = new OrbitCalculation();
            earthcoordinates = oe.earthOrbitCalculation(t);
            earth_x = earthcoordinates[0];
            earth_y = earthcoordinates[1];

            OrbitCalculation oa = new OrbitCalculation();
            asteroidcoordinates = oa.asteroidOrbitCalculation(t);
            asteroid_x = asteroidcoordinates[0];
            asteroid_y = asteroidcoordinates[1];


            OrbitCalculation os = new OrbitCalculation();
            shipcoordinates = os.shipOrbitCalculation(ship_t,keyheard, ship_x, ship_y);
            ship_x = shipcoordinates[0];
            ship_y = shipcoordinates[1];
            velocity_x = ship_x - ship_x_previous;
            velocity_y = ship_y - ship_y_previous;

            ship_x_previous = ship_x;
            ship_y_previous = ship_y;

            asteroid_x_previous = asteroid_x;
            asteroid_y_previous = asteroid_y;
            //System.out.println("key is" + keyheard);


            if(c.whoCollision() == "asteroid"){
                ship_x = asteroid_x;
                ship_y = asteroid_y;

                isCollision = true;
                velocity_x = 0;
                velocity_y = 0; 

                if(MineCalculation.can_start_mining == true){
                // you are now mining so can_start_mining must be false until you are done mining
                MineCalculation.can_start_mining = false;

                JFrame popup_want_to_mine = new JFrame();
                Icon pr_icon = new ImageIcon("pricon.gif");
                Object stringArray[] = {"Metals", "Rocket Fuel"};
                mining_choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(popup_want_to_mine, "What Would You Like To Mine?", "You Landed On 2002 TC70!",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, pr_icon, stringArray, stringArray[0]); 

                we_are_mining = true;
                }
                if(we_are_mining){

                    MineCalculation m = new MineCalculation();
                    // This step starts the mining process depending on the value of mining_choice
                    if(mining_choice == 0){
                        m.mining("Metals");
                    }
                    if(mining_choice == 1){
                        m.mining("Rocket Fuel");
                    }


                    if(!MineCalculation.is_mining){
                        we_are_mining = false;
                        if( mining_choice == 0){
                            System.out.println("You are done mining Metals!");
                            JFrame popup_done_mining = new JFrame();
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(popup_done_mining, "You are done mining for Metals");
                        }
                        if(mining_choice == 1){
                            System.out.println("You are done mining Rocket Fuel!");
                            JFrame popup_done_mining = new JFrame();
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(popup_done_mining, "You are done mining for Rocket Fuel");
                        }

                        t = 0;
                        keyheard = 0;
                        MineCalculation.can_start_mining = true;
                        MineCalculation.rocketfuel_amount = 0;
                        MineCalculation.metals_amount = 0;

                    }
                }


                /** Here a bit of code that produces a string called  
                 * mining_popup_answer which feeds into the
                 * MineCalculation.Mining() method  */

            }
            else if(c.whoCollision() == "earth"){
                ship_x = earth_x;
                ship_y = earth_y; 

                isCollision = true;
                velocity_x = 0;
                velocity_y = 0;
            }
            else{ 
                isCollision = false;}

            t = t + 1;
            ship_t = ship_t + 1;

            rocketfuel_text.setText(Double.toString(MineCalculation.rocketfuel_amount));
            repaint();
            metals_text.setText(Double.toString(MineCalculation.metals_amount));
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void keyListen(){

        InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_FOCUSED);
        ActionMap am = getActionMap();

        KeyStroke left_press = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false);
        im.put(left_press, "Left_Press");   
        am.put("Left_Press", new AbstractAction(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {keyheard = 1; }}); 

        KeyStroke left_release = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true);
        im.put(left_release, "Left_Release");   
        am.put("Left_Release", new AbstractAction(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {keyheard = 5;}});

        KeyStroke right_press = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false);
        im.put(right_press, "Right_Press"); 
        am.put("Right_Press", new AbstractAction(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {keyheard = 2;}}); 

        KeyStroke right_release = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true);
        im.put(right_release, "Right_Release"); 
        am.put("Right_Release", new AbstractAction(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {keyheard = 5;}});

        KeyStroke up_press = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false);
        im.put(up_press, "Up_Press");   
        am.put("Up_Press", new AbstractAction(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {keyheard = 3;}});    

        KeyStroke up_release = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, true);
        im.put(up_release, "Up_Release");   
        am.put("Up_Release", new AbstractAction(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {keyheard = 5;}});

        KeyStroke down_press = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false);
        im.put(down_press, "Down_Press");   
        am.put("Down_Press", new AbstractAction(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {keyheard = 4;}});  

        KeyStroke down_release = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true);
        im.put(down_release, "Down_Release");   
        am.put("Down_Release", new AbstractAction(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {keyheard = 5;}});

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! To make life easier for reviewers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does)

Answer (score 4):

For now, I can't help you with your problem, but maybe with the readability of your code:

- either use camelCase or snake_case, not both (it makes it really hard to guess what variable names might be, and makes your code harder to read). In Java, camelCase is customary.
- short variable names are not a good idea. What is `oe`, `oa`, `c` or `t`? And what is `ship_t`? And what is the difference between `shipA`, `ship`, `shipL`, etc? `timer` for what?
- use `equals` for string comparison instead of `==`.
- `t = t + 1` can be written as `t++`.
- define variables in as small a scope as possible. Many of your variables do not need to be class level.
- your class does too much. It would be a lot easier to read if you would split up the game logic and the game presentation. Also, having so many static variables hints to bad design (the first block is fine, but why are `earth_x`, etc all static as well?).
- you have too many newlines.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `enum` for enumerated values

The comparisons with the literal strings `"earth"` and `"asteroid"` are asking for trouble, for example here:

> ```
>     if(keyheard == 0 || c.whoCollision() == "earth"){g.drawImage(ship,ship_x, ship_y, this);}
>     else if(c.whoCollision() == "asteroid"){g.drawImage(shipA, ship_x, ship_y, this);}
> ```

Your program shouldn't rely on string literals.
If you make a typo,
or later change something in your program,
the compiler cannot know that something is wrong.
It seems you could replace these strings with a proper `enum`.

#### Chain mutually exclusive `if` conditions using `else if`

These two conditions cannot be true at the same time:

> ```
> if(mining_choice == 0){
>     m.mining("Metals");
> }
> if(mining_choice == 1){
>     m.mining("Rocket Fuel");
> }
> ```

In this code the second `if` will be evaluated even after the first was true.
That's pointless.
If you chain them using `else if`,
that won't happen:
if the first was true, the second condition won't be evaluated.

You do this at other places too. Review and correct everywhere.

#### Reduce duplicated anon classes using an inner class

It's really tedious to re-type the anonymous `AbstractAction` classes like this:

> ```
> am.put("Left_Press", new AbstractAction(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {keyheard = 1; }});
> am.put("Left_Release", new AbstractAction(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {keyheard = 5;}});
> am.put("Right_Press", new AbstractAction(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {keyheard = 2;}});
> am.put("Up_Press", new AbstractAction(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {keyheard = 3;}});
> ```

It's not good to copy-paste non-trivial logic.
It's better to create a nested class for this:

```
private class KeyPressAction extends AbstractAction {
    private final int key;

    private KeyPressAction(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        keyheard = key;
    }
}
```

This way you can simplify the above to:

```
am.put("Left_Press", new KeyPressAction(1));
am.put("Left_Release", new KeyPressAction(5));
am.put("Right_Press", new KeyPressAction(2));
am.put("Up_Press", new KeyPressAction(3));
```

Comment: janos I took much of your advice and rewrote and rearranged much of my code. Where should I post the revamped code? Someone suggested I self answer but my original question about timer's hasn't been figured out so I'm not sure where to put the edits.

Comment: Post it in a new question. With the obvious objections out of the way, and the code easier to read, you should get more interesting reviews.

Comment: Thank you Janos =) I reposted here. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83010/timer-for-java-game-updated